# Is it considered improper to upvote more than one answer in the same post?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, upvotes

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I have recently earned the ability to upvote and downvote answers. I understand that downvoting should be used conservatively in cases only where the answer is bad, violates community expectations, is unhelpful/wrong, etc.

But what do I do when I find more than one answer to a question especially helpful (assuming I am not the OP and cannot select the check mark for the answer that solved the problem)? Should voters be choosing only one answer and giving their vote to it, or is it alright to upvote more liberally?

Comment: You can vote on any answer. Vote on the _content_ of the answer, not on the context of other answers or the user posting it.

Comment: "downvoting should be used conservatively" - this is very controversial. Some people like to never downvote as "not nice" (I believe IRL they also remove "Road Closed" signs as not nice) while others prefer downvotes to lengthy pointless comments...

Comment: Downvoting should not be used any more conservatively than upvoting. They are the only way you have to express your opinion of the correctness and usefulness of a post. Vote often, as your heart moves you. If there are multiple helpful answers, upvote ‘em all. If they all have problems, downvote ‘em all. Or any combination thereof.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Up-vote any content you find useful or deem up-vote worthy, and the same can be said for down-voting, reversed.

There is no restriction to how many answers you can up-vote in a single question - there is a restriction to the number of votes you get daily, IIRC, it is capped at 40 (as corrected by [@AlexeiLevenkov](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov)). I've recently started to go through the posts an up-vote all the useful answers to show my appreciation to the answerers.

However, you are right, only a single answer can be check-marked and that can only be done by the OP.

**TL;DR**

'*Is it considered improper to upvote more than one answer in the same post?*' - No.